# How to make onLocationChange that records speed limit, save data in local SQL database once? Currently it is triggered every second

Tags: java, android

The current onLocationChange Event looks like this. This event is triggerred every second.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    float speed = location.getSpeed();

    if ( speed  >= 60){

        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude.toString();
        latitude.toString();
        String speedStr = String.valueOf(speed);
        textViewSpeed.setText(speedStr);
        //inserting some records
        dateTime = new Date(location.getTime());
        db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO 'data' VALUES('"+ longitude +"','"+ latitude +" ',' " + speedStr + " ', '"+ dateTime+ "');");

     }
}
```

Comment: When exactly do you wish to save the values in database ? Your location event seems to be triggered every second.

Comment: The concept is that when the user passed the speed limit this must be saved in my local database, not every second. for instance, if my pace is 61 km for 1 minute I don't want to save 60 records just only one.

Comment: Joe my apologies, it will not happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag variable as shown below.

```
//Define a class level static variable flag
private static boolean isSaved = false;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    float speed = location.getSpeed();

    if ( speed  >= 60 && !isSaved) {

        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude.toString();
        latitude.toString();
        String speedStr = String.valueOf(speed);
        textViewSpeed.setText(speedStr);

        //inserting some records
        dateTime = new Date(location.getTime());
        db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO 'data' VALUES('"+ longitude +"','"+ latitude +" ',' " + speedStr + " ', '"+ dateTime+ "');");

        //Saved the data once
        isSaved = true;

     }else{
        isSaved = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Does location.getSpeed() give correct values ? Please check in debug mode if the control enters if..else block. Can you please post your entire class code ?